# Как сделать переадресацию query_string

Tags: .htaccess

В cms изменились параметры в запросах, теперь вместо ?157=параметр нужно ?157[]=параметр как htaccess переадресовать с r=301, сейчас сделал только так

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)157=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)ruchki(.*)$ /404 [L,R=404]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?157=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1157[]=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Если в адресной строке обязательны `ruchki`, то так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?157=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*ruchki.*)$ /$1?%1157[]=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: [ссылка](http://ilempi.ru/catalog/mebelnye-ruchki?157=скоба) только параметры кодируются в проценты, как это можно исправить?

Comment: кодируются дополнительными числами 25, откуда они

Comment: 25 это % в percent-encoding, кодирует уже закодированные символы

Comment: @netoniel, зашел, 301 редирект прошел, русские буквы, которые были кодированы через `%hex-число` отобразились нормально.

Comment: Ага, добавил NE параметр теперь не кодирует/декодирует ))